# How can I make the trees straight?

Tags: particles

I have a problem. Some of the trees are horizontal. I tried to straighten the hairs in Particle Edit, but it didn’t work.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (keep only the necessary items)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I did. Did it work?

Comment: you need to share the URL it will generate  ;)

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: once you've uploaded the file, it will generate a URL, you need to copy it and paste it here

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/6/c/6c89cdcc91118967146ea3805078f42e.blend Is that the right link?

Comment: @Allen Simpson, I don't think that your link answers his question

Comment: yes, unfortunately that did not help!

Comment: my answer helps ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. delete edit

[image]

2. apply scale to "Cube"
3. cylinder 8: tracking axis +z

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: oh my god, you were too fast this time :((

Comment: ok....do i HAVE TO delete my answer so that you are not mad at me? ;)

Comment: don't worry I'm going to time travel and you'll remember nothing in several seconds

Comment: so you are superman AND man in black!?

Comment: come on, don't you know, the one and only Superman (Christopher Reeves 1978) can make the earth go counterclockwise

Comment: Sounds like Men in Black! :^)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: @Chris ... you are one of the biggest influencer here, thanks for that ... but I would like to ask you - please, please, please ... can you grab your screenshots in wide or square proportion with setup panels filling like half of screenshot max? Even from first image I already know it is your answer ... those oversized panels always punch me to my face :) Thank you if you can do this little thing for me :)

Comment: @vklidu: Thank you! ;) i will try. I cannot promise that i can always do it because my memory isn't the best...but i try. Sorry for punching in your face ;)